# Submitted form based on entity class changes user token automatically

Tags: php, forms, symfony, token

I just started studying Symfony and faced a problem.
I have typical User entity class, with fields like "name", "email", "password" etc.

\Form\UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', null, ['data' => 'Type in your password'])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

\Controller\UserController.php

```
/* Some code */

/**
 * @Route("id{id}/edit", name="user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, User $user, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    /* Some code */

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

\templates\user\edit.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ app.user.username }} profile{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Edit user {{ app.user.username }}</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <a href="{{ path('user_index', {'id': app.user.id}) }}">back</a>

{% endblock %}
```

After form submitting, the token will automatically change according to the entered data. As a result, the user is deauthorized. How can this be corrected? I just want to get the data from the form, without changing the token.

Comment: So don’t use the user entity. Forms don’t need entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way the Symfony security component works. When a user's details are changed, the information stored in the token are invalidated and the user needs to re-authenticate. There is an issue on the Symfony repository explaining the behaviour with some ideas on working around this, have a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35501#issuecomment-579799666